# Why isn't bloc builder recognizing the state change? If I wrap emit in a Future.delayed(Duration.zero) it works fine

Tags: flutter, bloc, emit

I'm working on a flutter project and all of a sudden, the bloc builder I was using stopped recognizing a specific state change. Here is an example of the code

```
class ProfileBloc extends HydratedBloc<ProfileEvent, ProfileState>
...

 on<ProfileSelected>(_mapProfileSelectedToState);

...

  FutureOr<void> _mapProfileSelectedToState(
      ProfileSelected event, Emitter<ProfileState> emit) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(
      profileSelectionStatus: ProfileSelectionStatus.selecting,
    ));

    setHeaders();
    setRedirect();

    emit(state.copyWith(
      selectedProfile: event.selectedProfile
      profileSelectionStatus: ProfileSelectionStatus.selected,
    ));
   }
```

```
...

BlocBuilder<ProfileBloc,ProfileState>(builder: (context, profileState) {
  
      return profileState.profileSelectionStatus == ProfileSelectionStatus.selected ? Text("Profile Selected") : Text("Profile Not Selected");
    }

...
```

when the BlocBuilder runs, it never registers the `ProfileSelectionStatus.selected` state. It always returns `Profile Not Selected`. That is until I refresh the browser, then it reports as `Profile Selected`.  If I wrap the second emit(the profileSelected one) in the bloc in a `Future.delayed(Duration.zero,()=>emit...)`, then the bloc builder works as expected returning `Profile Selected` after it's emitted.

The thing is, it worked for a long time, then without changing those two blocs of code, it stopped working. Any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: Looks everything alright. Make sure your copyWith method returns a new object instead of mutating the same object property. I know it's a dumb advice but sometimes the issue could be this as well. Also, if you have equals operator overriden for your state class, make sure it considers profileSelectionStatus as well. If bloc find the current state object and new state object are same, it won't call blocbuilder or bloclistener.

Comment: I guess should add that it calls the bloc builder, but not with the latest emitted state

Comment: does UserState extends ProfileState? Try changing the signature of _mapProfileSelectedToState's emit to Emitter<ProfileState> and see if it works.

Comment: good catch there, but that was just a typo, it's supposed to be profile state.